# Delete object from memory in javascript

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am working on an AJAX application with a lot of Javascript. All pages are loaded through AJAX.
On a certain page I have a grid which is build in Javascript. Now when I leave that page I want to destroy that grid. I call jQuery.remove() but this only deletes the object from the DOM.
My question is how can I delete this grid object from the memory? Cause it still exists when I move away from the page.

Much appreciated!

Comment: How do you know that this object still exists in memory after you navigate away from the page?

Comment: Do you store grid identifier in variable? If so then make gridVar = null;

Comment: It's completely up to the browser... I guess you assume it still exist in memory because the browser process memory usage is not decreasing?

Comment: When I open the firebug console I can see the object still exists. It's only deleted from the DOM.

Comment: firebug can't really tell what is in the memory and what isn't in the memory, I would look for more "reliable" tool if you're really into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you delete all references to your grid (i.e. assign null to the variable), the garbage collector will delete the object from memory.

Comment: This would work if there is an actual unload event fired but because this is an all ajax app this is not happening.

Comment: An option could be to call an unload event everytime you navigate through your ajax application. This isn't a nice solution though..

Answer (score 1):

put the grid into a div or anything you want.
when you want to delete it use

```
$("<the name of the div>").empty();
```

that will clear it.