# Clear object memory in javascript

Tags: javascript, tibco-gi

I am using General Interface in my web application and I have javascript classes and methods to create objects for my classes. I would like to clear the memory when the objects are not used.
My question is how can I clear the object's memory.

I have tried with 'obj = null;' and 'delete obj;'. Both are not working as expected.

Is there way to clear the object and object memory in JavaScript or in General Interface.

-Sridhar

Comment: Javascript already has a garbage collector that clear any unused references in memory.

Comment: I think already the question is asked ,check this link below
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115054/delete-object-from-memory-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. As long as every reference is really removed (e.g. setting to `null` as many have suggested), it's entirely up to the GC as to when it'll run and when it'll collect them.

Answer (score 1):

try to set to `null`.

```
var a = new className();
alert(a);

a = null;
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Self-Invoking Functions](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

```
Self-invoking functions are functions who execute immediately, and create their own closure. Take a look at this:

(function () {
    var dog = "German Shepherd";
    alert(dog);
})();
alert(dog); // Returns undefined

so the dog variable was only available within that context
```

**EDIT**
If memory leak is related to DOM, [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks) written how to manage it. So, i tried to solve like that:

```
var obj = {};//your big js object
//do something with it

function clear() {
    var that = this;
    for (var i in that) {
        clear.call(that[i]);
        that[i] = null;
    }
}

clear.call(obj);//clear it's all properties
obj = null;
```

Comment: I understand these things very well. But I would like to free the memory explicitly. Since, my objects are globally used and the memory has to be cleared when these objects are no needed further.